# Spring boot application intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

The autowiring and the bean detection feature are not working for my spring boot application. The application is running fine it's just that intellij does not detect correctly the beans. I have added the Spring facet, hibernate facet, jpa facet to the module.

Here is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml")
public class MyApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in IntelliJ. However proper Spring Boot support is planned for the 14.1 release (last time I checked this release should be ready in a few months). Check out [IDEA-119230](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119230) for more details.